# action="" not working in WordPress

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, action

I'm trying to make a custom contact form using a custom page template in WordPress. When I use

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

it goes from the contact page to the index page. When I leave action empty like

action=""

it gives me an error. Can anyone give me some insight on this? I can post the whole page if you you'd like. I read similar post but didn't find a solid answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get the error message I wrote for when the function dies. I know something is wrong with the action because it's wordpress and slightly more complicated.

Comment: I also know it's the action because there will be an error message saying that the URL doesn't exist even when I put a full URL to the custom template page.

Comment: Can you explain what it's supposed to do in more detail? I could guess the desired outcome, but it would be a waste of time.

Comment: I have a custom contact page template in wordpress. On it is a custom form with the php script on the same page. When I test the script with its method as post and form action as ="". I get an error saying the page doesn't exist. Probably because of wordpress's pretty links url set up. You know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of PHP_SELF. WordPress rewrites everything to it's index.php, so you need to post to the current url and not the index.php.